# How to prevent style tags of unused React components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I think this question may expand beyond React, but I'm still not sure if React itself is responsible for the problem.

The environment is React with TypeScript. I use CSS imports in the component files, so that each component has its specific stylesheet and I presume that those styles will not be added to the `<head>` element until the respective component is instantiated. But it turns out that if I import a component from a file, which just reexports all of them, the styles of all the other components, which I do not use, are still added in the DOM.

Here is a simple example, let's say I have two simple components in the `lib` folder - `Avatar` and `Button`. They look like this (the `Button` is similar):

```
import React from 'react';

import './avatar.css';

const Avatar: React.FC = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="avatar">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
export { Avatar };
```

Then I add `index.ts` to reexport the components, in order to have simple import path:

```
import { Avatar } from './Avatar';
import { Button } from './Button';

export { Avatar, Button };
```

And finally, in my `AppComponent` I want to use only the `Button` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from './lib';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <Button>example</Button>      
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

To my surprise, in the `<head>` element there are `<style>` tags not only for the `Button`, but also for the `Avatar`. Why is this happening? Is my reexport configuration wrong?

Notice that if I import the component directly from its file - `import { Button } from './lib/Button'` I do not get the `Avatar` styles.

The example is really simple, but the real scenario is related to a React component library, which contains a lot of components with a lot of stylesheets. I want to avoid inserting so many `<style>` tags  in the DOM, unless they are really needed.

Thank you for spending time on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so that each component has its specific stylesheet and I presume that those styles will not be added to the  element until the respective component is instantiated

This presumption is wrong. React uses webpack to bundle its files and the way webpack works for CSS imports is that it loads all the CSS files that your project depends on and put them in the `<head>` element right at the beginning.

---

You might ask: Then how do I keep my styles separated and don't get them mixed.
**There are three solutions to this**

1. A good way is to [Add a CSS Modules Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)
2. Another suggestion is to make the `<div>` that wraps your component have a `className` that is the same name as the component so your component will look like this

```
export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
...
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="ComponentOne">
        ...
      </div
    )
  }
}
```

And your component CSS file will look like:

```
.ComponentOne div img {
  ...
}
.ComponentOne .class-one {
 ...
}
```

With this way, using CSS preprocessor like SASS will come in handy, so your .scss file will simply begin with:

```
.ComponentOne {
  ...
}
```

3. Another solution is to have the styles as an object inside your component. This way the style will only be scoped to your component and will be removed when the component unmounts, but then you will lose the ability to easily create `@media queries` and`other special effects like`:hover` plus this approach is not recommended for small components that get mounted and unmounted too often because this creates a performance issue once the application gets larger

---

You also might ask: since all the style sheets get imported at the begging, then why don't I put all my styles in one big style sheet and not splitting them up.

Other than the fact that splitting your styles will make them easy to handle so that each component will have its separate CSS file and webpack will handle importing them, There is one other benefit:
Say you have a *feature1 component* which also has a *feature1.css* file. In the beginning, when you have feature1 imported in your main app, webpack will also import its style sheet and put it in the `<head>` element.
But say in the future you decided you don't want to use *feature1 component* anymore and you are using another *feature2 component* now which has its own *feature2.css* file. Now since no other component is importing *feature1 component*, webpack will also ignore importing *feature1.css* into the `<head>` element.

Comment: Thank you so much for the well arranged answer! Could I ask you to elaborate a bit more on the second point about the `div` wrapper - is it related to the CSS Modules from the first point? And one more question, does the example with `feature1` and `feature2` components make use of those CSS Modules again?

Comment: I edited the answer to provide more explanation of the second point. So to answer your question: No, the second point is not related to CSS Modules. Although you can use CSS Modules the same way as to point two, it won't really be considered CSS Module anymore. Refer to the added code in the updated answer to get the idea of what I mean.

Comment: `feature1` and `feature2` example: The example was mainly directed to the import of CSS files; if you didn't import one file, say `feature1.css`, in any of your projects files, then webpack will not add that file to the `<head>` element. But CSS Modules will also be treated the same: If you created a Module but didn't import it in any file, then webpack will not bundle it with the rest of your project.

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. It seems that the only approach, that prevents unused style imports in the `<head>` is the third point (styles as an object), which, however has limitations. All the other options just help with keeping stylesheets separate. Can we conclude that it is not possible to do `import { Button } from './lib';` without having the styles of all other components from `lib`  imported in the `<head>`?